# Putty connect fast, Ubuntu (linux) terminal not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

When I connect in my cloud by Windows, using PUTTY, the connection is established in about 3 seconds maximum.

When I connect by Ubuntu, it's "loading, loading, loading" ... and about 10 seconds later asks for password, and then waiting another 2 seconds, it connects.

Why is that?

**[EDIT]**
**[debug] -v**

```
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/patrick/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Have you attempted verbose mode when using ssh?  You can do it with the -v switch and go up to -vvv.

Comment: enable debugging on the linux shell for `ssh` with adding a `-v` to the cmdline and post the output including a mark at the position where it hangs.

Comment: Maybe, ssh tries to connect with public key authentication first, before resorting to password authentication.

Comment: See debug in post: @Shah

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting by ip rather than the hostname. Sometimes lags occur when the name resolution is taking too long.

Comment: I ever connect by ip, never by hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Comment: I really hope this works. I have been going crazy with this error for days